# Typing in Sides of paper in Latex

Tags: typography

I wanted to type something which was consist of two parts.  I wanted to type the first part in left side and the other part, in the same line, but in the left side of paper such as which is written in the image. How can I do it?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps with a `tabular` environment with `lr` columntypes, however, with some width specification

Comment: Look for the `\hfill` command.

Comment: Dears
I don't know how to type such style in Latex!

Comment: A typical line of your code will be `left stuff \hfill right stuff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write something like :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textbf{CURRENT POSITION}

\textbf{University of California, Los Angeles}\hfill Los Angeles, CA

Postdoctoral fellow\hfill 2013-present

\end{document}
```

which will give you this :

[image]

Comment: Dear DRi,

I'd like to thank you so much :).
This is what I wanted.